# Why cant I override Semantic UI CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, semantic-ui

I'm trying to override Semantic UI's CSS styling, however, it's not working, even though I'm giving a specific class name to the relevant class. Here is my code:

```
return (
    <div className="ui grid">
        <div className="three column row">
            <div className="four wide column" ></div>
            <div className="text eight wide column"> <h1>Team Selection</h1></div>
            <div className="four wide column"></div>    
        </div>
        <div className= "three column row">
            <div className="four wide column"></div>
            <div className="eight wide column" style={style1}> </div>
            <div className="four wide column"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
)
```

CSS file:

```
.text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Either as @N'Bayramberdiyev mentioned, or you can add ``!important`` to the end of each value, as in ``display: flex !important;`` to tell the CSS processor that your rule should overwrite conflicting rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more specific rules to override other styles.

> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration,
>   determined by the number of each selector type in the matching
>   selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last
>   declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity
>   only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple
>   declarations. As per CSS rules, directly targeted elements will always
>   take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its
>   ancestor.

Read more about [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```css
.ui.grid > .row > .column.text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="three column row">
        <div class="four wide column" ></div>
        <div class="text eight wide column"> <h1>Team Selection</h1></div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="three column row">
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
        <div class="eight wide column"> </div>
        <div class="four wide column"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```